# What would prevent an SOQL query to not returning data when execuited in APEX code but return data when ran from Eclipse?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have an APEX class that executes an SOQL query that returns an sObject. The query is this (as I copied from my debug log):

```
SELECT Paid_To_Date__c, ShippingCity__c, BillingCity__c, Invoice_Source__c, 
  BillingState__c, Status__c, Account__c, BillingPostalCode__c, ShippingState__c, 
  ShippingPostalCode__c, Discount__c, Invoice_Comments__c, LastActivityDate, 
  CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, Id, ShippingStreet__c, ShippingCountry__c, 
  Contact_Email__c, BillingStreet__c, Name, IsDeleted, PO_Number__c, 
  AutoNumber__c, Company_Name__c, SystemModstamp, Contact__c, Date_of_Issue__c, 
  Balance__c, CreatedDate, OwnerId, Terms__c, Tax_Total__c, Contact_Name__c, 
  BillingCountry__c, Subtotal__c, Invoice_Total__c, LastModifiedById, Matter__c, (
    SELECT List_Price__c,Tax_Amount_1__c,Tax_Name_2__c,Tax_Name_1__c,
      Item_Total__c,Tax_Name_3__c,Tax_Rate_3__c,Tax_Amount_3__c,
      Item_SKU__c,Quantity__c,Tax_Amount_2__c,Tax_Rate_2__c,
      Item_Description__c,Tax_Rate_1__c,Item_Name__c
    FROM Invoice_Line_Items__r
    ORDER BY Quantity__c ASC,List_Price__c ASC,Item_Total__c ASC,
      Item_SKU__c ASC,Item_Name__c ASC
    ) 
FROM Invoice__c
WHERE Id = 'a0a9000000CF7qIAAT'
LIMIT 1
```

Now it shows like this in my debug log:

```
12:59:47.287 (287447000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[115]|Database.query(String)
12:59:47.290 (290769000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[115]|Aggregations:1|select Paid_To_Date__c, ShippingCity__c, BillingCity__c, Invoice_Source__c, BillingState__c, Status__c, Account__c, BillingPostalCode__c, ShippingState__c, ShippingPostalCode__c, Discount__c, Invoice_Comments__c, LastActivityDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, Id, ShippingStreet__c, ShippingCountry__c, Contact_Email__c, BillingStreet__c, Name, IsDeleted, PO_Number__c, AutoNumber__c, Company_Name__c, SystemModstamp, Contact__c, Date_of_Issue__c, Balance__c, CreatedDate, OwnerId, Terms__c, Tax_Total__c, Contact_Name__c, BillingCountry__c, Subtotal__c, Invoice_Total__c, LastModifiedById, Matter__c, (select List_Price__c,Tax_Amount_1__c,Tax_Name_2__c,Tax_Name_1__c,Item_Total__c,Tax_Name_3__c,Tax_Rate_3__c,Tax_Amount_3__c,Item_SKU__c,Quantity__c,Tax_Amount_2__c,Tax_Rate_2__c,Item_Description__c,Tax_Rate_1__c,Item_Name__c from Invoice_Line_Items__r order by Quantity__c ASC,List_Price__c ASC,Item_Total__c ASC,Item_SKU__c ASC,Item_Name__c ASC) from Invoice__c where Id = 'a0a9000000CF7qIAAT' limit 1
12:59:47.306 (306041000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[115]|Rows:0
12:59:47.306 (306170000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[115]|Database.query(String)
```

Notice the "Rows: 0" in the log. But when I run this query in Eclipse query editor it runs fine and returns the record it intends to open.

The Above class code is associated with a Visualforce intend to generate a PDF and I'm trying to generate the PDF via code and save it as attachment like this:

```
PageReference invPdf                = Page.InvoicePDF;
invPdf.getParameters().put('sourceid', invoice.Id);
blob b                              = invPdf.getContentAsPdf();

att                                 = new Attachment();
att.Body                            = b;
att.Name                            = invoice.Name+'.pdf';
att.ContentType                     = 'application/pdf';
att.ParentId                        = invoice.Id;
insert att;
```

Can anyone suggest why would it behave like this? if I open the InvoicePDF vf page with "sourceid" parameter passed with value as provided above it opens up the PDF correctly with data.

Comment: One thought would be that in Eclipse, you are running without any sharing restrictions, while, depending on how your class is written, you may have "with sharing" enabled. Could it be that when you are running the code via the page, you don't have visibility to the record you are expecting to see?

Comment: No I don't think so. because it is my dev org and I'm the System Admin.

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is connected to the same org? Can you navigate directly to the record in the UI?

Comment: Yes definitely it is from the same org. I even tried running the query after copying directly from system debug logs into the new Developer Console and it returned the data correctly. It is only when I try to run it in my function which infact is initiatited as a Javascript Remoting method causing this query to not return data at all. But as I know of date JS Remoting does not have any limitations of this kind.

Comment: I once had a similar situation and it was related to the API version of the class (earlier version) preventing the retrieval of the rows, while eclipse (latest version) was retrieving the row ! I am not sure if this is relevant to your case though, it's just an idea...

Comment: I tried changing the API versions as well. My VF page and Class both were updated to latest ones. Right now they are using 27.0